# Как я могу отследить нажатие на крестик в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, closeevent

Как в приложении я могу отследить нажатие на крестик (закрытие окна приложения).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('MyApp')


if __name__ == '__main__':         
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой крестик, закрытие программы? я думаю все это гуглится...

Comment: А считывать и записывать отдельную строку в файл вы уже научились?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо переопределить метод `closeEvent()`.

> void QWidget::**closeEvent**(QCloseEvent *event) [virtual protected]
>
> Этот обработчик событий вызывается с данным `event`, когда *Qt* получает запрос на закрытие окна для виджета верхнего уровня от оконной системы.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('myapp')
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Переопределить colseEvent
        reply = QMessageBox.question\
        (self, 'Вы нажали на крестик',
            "Вы уверены, что хотите уйти?",
             QMessageBox.Yes,
             QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == '__main__':         
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]